# How to find out BIOS scheme?

Tags: bios

I want to find out if my old HP has MBR partition scheme
I've tried this

```
dmidecode 3.0
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.4 present.
19 structures occupying 891 bytes.
Table at 0x7FCC4000.

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
        Vendor: Hewlett-Packard
        Version: 68PZD Ver. F.0D
        Release Date: 04/07/2009
        Address: 0xF0000
        Runtime Size: 64 kB
        ROM Size: 2048 kB
        Characteristics:
                PCI is supported
                PC Card (PCMCIA) is supported
                BIOS is upgradeable
                BIOS shadowing is allowed
                Boot from CD is supported
                Selectable boot is supported
                EDD is supported
                Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
                8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
                Serial services are supported (int 14h)
                Printer services are supported (int 17h)
                ACPI is supported
                USB legacy is supported
                Smart battery is supported
                BIOS boot specification is supported
                Function key-initiated network boot is supported
                Targeted content distribution is supported
        BIOS Revision: 15.13
        Firmware Revision: 95.29

Handle 0x000A, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
        Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
        Product Name: HP Compaq 6830s
        Version: F.0D
        Serial Number: CNU9204GB7
        UUID: E4F1121F-C074-DE11-B790-40D25F06206F
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        SKU Number: NN327ES#ABB
        Family: 103C_5336AN

Handle 0x000B, DMI type 2, 16 bytes
Base Board Information
        Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
        Product Name: 30E9
```

But I can't find this information.Is there any alternative command to

```
sudo dmidecode | less ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disk partitioning scheme is local to the disk, and can be different on disks on the same system. Try the `fdisk` or `gdisk` programs.